# In Corda V2, are there limitations on the size and scope of attachments?

Tags: corda

In Corda V2, what are the limitations on the types of attachments that can be used?

- Do they have to obey a specific format?
- Is there an upper limit on size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attachments must be JAR files.

There is no explicit limit on attachment size. However, there is an implicit limit in Corda V2 because the network stack doesn’t process messages over 10MB.